# How can I set "Quiet Time" when using Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: android, ios, azure, azure-notificationhub

I have a situation where we've switched from handling all of our notifications in-house to using the notification hub in Azure.  This has worked fine so far and has been much more reliable.

Now there is a request for the ability for each mobile device to define a "quiet time" for my application only.  I know there is a way to do this on the devices themselves, but the user just want the ability to mute any notifications from this app during certain time periods.

Since I no longer have control over which device gets which message, how can I do this?  Is this a "tag" strategy?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the Microsoft page on Notification Hub tag expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx). You could register each device with tags for time zone or for blocks of time (adjusted based on time zone) when they should (or should not) receive notifications.

Then send the notifications to e.g. (hockeyfans && tenam) for devices registered to users who want notifications on hockey updates and for whom 10 a.m. time is a good time to receive them.